# React && Flux confused about where to put data

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'm developing a web app with React + Flux. But sometimes, I am confused about where to put the data of a component.

Flux says that we should keep the data in the store. When the data changed, store should emit a `change` event, then the react components which listen to the store's change event should call `setState` with the data in the store.

But in this way, one react component is made by two parts, which are the component it self, and the store to be listened. Sometimes I want the component to be more individual. I don't want some state of this component to be related to any store, so I store the state in the component jsx file. In this way it is not a flux style, but just react.

I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing. Should a fluxible app to be totally obey the flux or not?

Comment: maybe you will just have to create ANOTHER store which fits the individual needs of your component?

Comment: If I create ANOTHER store, the component is still associate with that store. `Individual` means that the component should not associate with any store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right answer to this question.
You could differentiate between application state and view state just as much as you could reason that all state should live in one global store.

**Application state** *could* be User information, product information or that type of data whereas **view state** could be related to toggling a div or what color a link should have depending on the application state.

These two approaches are both used in the wild and there is just a matter of preference.

[This is a good read](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2014/12/25/react-js-flux-om-i-am-trying-to-think-it-through/) that argues for the case of a single state.
I won't link to the other reasoning as it's the "flux way" and an easy Google

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For my understanding from this, **Application state** more like a **business involved behavior state**, and **view state** is like a **component user interface behavior state**.  Plus, normally the **Application state** is putted in the `flux store` while the **view state** often put in the `component` it self ,  is this right ?

Comment: Exactly - That's _one_ way of reasoning about it! :)

Comment: Cool, this is also what I'm doing till now.