# Re-rendering a single component, is all data needed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If i have a large app with a list of online users and one of the users logs off, it would be quite simple to have React remove the user giving it a list of the current users.
If the list is big, the client could have a local cache and have the server to only remove 1 user from this before rendering. Simpe enough for me to deal with.

As far as I've understood, the recommended approach using React, is to wrap your entire application within a single  component, and then have a lot of sub-components. At least if you're using React for the entire UI. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Now when a users logs off, I would not only need to have a local variable containing the online users, it would have to contain everything needed to render the rest of my application that isn't static, so that React could do the diffing in the Shadow DOM.

I'm pretty sure that there's something I'm missing. Someone who can help me understand this?

Comment: Currently I am doing the same thing as you do, which is wrap all the sub-components in a `Application` component. And all the demos from Yahoo I have watched so far also do the same thing.

Comment: I haven't really used React much yet, I've only tried a few things with it so far. Do you have a huge variable containing all the states of your app?
I'm currently thinking the only way to update a single component, would be by updating this big ugly variable, and then passing the entire thing back to React.render(<App>,fn())...

Comment: Nah, some variable of a component's state should be in that component, while some other variable should be in the top component, it depends. Like a component of date picker, the date data should be only in that component, you can write a function for other components get the date data from the date picker. For further you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301778/react-flux-confused-about-where-to-put-data

Comment: It's recommended to using the Flux way to build your react app.